# Default constructor invocation difference between C++14 and C++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, variadic-templates

Consider the following code (question follows below):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Type0
{
    Type0(char* c)
    {}
};

struct Type1
{
    Type1(int* i=nullptr) : i_(i)
    {}

    Type1(const Type1& other) = default;

    int* i_;
};

template <typename ...>
struct Composable;

template <typename T0, typename ... T>
struct Composable<T0, T...> : T0, Composable<T...>
{
    Composable()
    {
        std::cout << "Default Invoked: " << sizeof...(T) << std::endl;
    }

    Composable(const Composable& other) = default;

    template<typename Arg, typename ... Args>
    Composable(Arg&& arg, Args&& ... args) :
        T0(std::forward<Arg>(arg)), Composable<T...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) 
    {
        std::cout << "Non-default invoked: " << sizeof...(T) << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
struct Composable<>{};

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    char c='c';

    auto comp = Composable<Type0, Type1>(&c, &i);

    std::cout << comp.i_ << std::endl;
}
```

You can find the live code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ec944b6d0758d93). This code has an interesting property: depending on whether you compile it with the `--std=C++17` or `--std=C++14` option, the behaviour changes (you can try this in my link to the live code: edit the g++ invocation `--std` parameter in the bottom left).

With `--std=c++14`, you get the following output:

```
Non-default invoked: 0
Non-default invoked: 1
Default Invoked: 0
Non-default invoked: 1
0x0
```

With `--std=C++17`, you get this instead:

```
Non-default invoked: 0
Non-default invoked: 1
0x7ffcdf02766c
```

To me, this difference is baffling. It seems clear that the C++17 version is doing the correct thing, and the C++14 is wrong. The C++14 version is invoking the default constructor of both `Composable` and (from it) `Type1` (this is where the `0x0` final line of output comes from, as `Type1` provides this as the default value for its `i` constructor parameter). However, I don't see any place where the default constructor is supposed to be invoked.

Furthermore, if I comment out the default constructor of `Composable` altogether, the C++17 version does exactly the same thing as before, whereas the C++14 version now fails to compile, complaining about the lack of a default constructor. If there was any hope of the difference being somehow explained by different optimization behavior, this fact surely kills it (the hope was anyhow small as the observed difference persists at all optimization levels, including 0).

Can anyone explain this difference? Is the C++14 behaviour a bug, or some intended behaviour which I do not understand? If the C++14 behaviour is correct within the rules of C++14, can someone please explain where the default constructor calls are coming from?

Comment: `Composable(Arg&& arg, Args&& ... args) : ... , Composable<T...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`. I find it interesting that this doesn't call the default constructor in C++17. It looks a lot like it should. Edit: why it shouldn't: `sizeof...(T) == sizeof...(args)` (should be), so it should call the default constructor of `Composable<>`, but there's a specialization for that

Comment: I've removed the `reinterpret_cast`. Please actually read the question

Comment: I'm assuming in C++14 `Composable<T...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` gets called a second time as `Composable<void>(void) ` so that is why you see the default constructor and the bad address.  I'm not sure why it is doing that though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guaranteed copy elision.

This line:

```
auto comp = Composable<Type0, Type1>(&c, &i);
```

In C++17, this means exactly the same thing as:

```
Composable<Type0, Type1> comp(&c, &i);
```

And if you change to this version, you'll see the same behavior bewteen C++14 and C++17. However, in C++14, that is still a move construction (or, more technically correct as you'll see in a minute, copy-initialization). But in `Composable`, you don't have an implicitly generated move constructor because you have a user-declared copy constructor. As a result, for the move construction, your "Non-default invoked" constructor template gets invoked (it's a better match than the copy constructor) in the C++14 version:

```
template<typename Arg, typename ... Args>
Composable(Arg&& arg, Args&& ... args) :
    T0(std::forward<Arg>(arg)), Composable<T...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Here, `Arg` is `Composable<Type0, Type1>` and `Args` is an empty pack. We delegate to `T0` (`Type0`)'s constructor, forwarding the whole `Composable` (which works because it inherits from `Type0` publicly, so we get the implicitly-generated move constructor there) and to `Composable<Type1>`'s default constructor (because `args` is empty).

This constructor template isn't *really* a proper move constructor - it doesn't end up initializing the `Type1` member at all. Instead of moving from the right hand side's `Type1::i_` you're invoking `Type1::Type1()`, the default constructor,  which is why you end up with `0`.

If you add a proper move constructor:

```
Composable(Composable&& other) = default;
```

Then you would again see the same behavior between C++14 and C++17.

Comment: That’s a decent answer, however I think it leaves one thing unclear: where is the default constructor invocation for Composable coming from in the C++14 version?

Comment: @Smeeheey Better?

Comment: I had to read that quite a few times. But yes, I get it now. Good answer. In case you were wondering, this is not a hypothetical question but a real problem observed in our (c++14) production candidate code, which you have helped to resolve